# Running out of memory while storing lots of data in redis

Tags: php, redis, phpredis, predis

I'm trying to execute this query in PHP Redis (*Predis*):

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10000000; $i++) {
    $client->SADD('key:'.$i, $i);
}
```

This code takes a long time, but it shouldn't run out of memory, besides, I've edited my `php.ini` file and changed `memory_limit` to `5000M`!

But, after that change, I'm still getting this error:

> **Fatal Error:** Allowed memory size xxxxxxxxxxxx exhausted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a key value in memory store I.e it uses ram to store. You have changed the memory limit of php not of Redis. The sadd function is adding to the Redis. Try to find how Redis uses ram to store